# can't resolve symbol '__aeabi_d2iz'

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-platform

I have cross compiled a little C source for an ARM architecture. Compiling and linking went OK, but at runtime I have got this error : can't resolve symbol '__aeabi_d2iz'.

I have pointed out that the problem comes from an explicit cast between int and double. Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong ? Casting a float value causes no problem.

Here are the compilation and link options I used :

```
arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc -mcpu=arm920t -mtune=arm920t -mapcs-frame -mapcs-stack-check -fno-stack-limit -Wall -c test.c -o test.o
arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc -mcpu=arm920t -mtune=arm920t -mapcs-frame -mapcs-stack-check -fno-stack-limit -D_REENTRANT -o test.x test.o -lm
```

Here is the source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double dTest = 123.456;

    i = (int)dTest; // <--- runtime error : can't resolve symbol '__aeabi_d2iz'
    printf("Converted i=%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread that as a link-time error, but now knowing that you're cross-compiling: are the libraries you're linking against the exact same ones on the target at runtime? (loaded question; they almost certainly aren't)

Answer (score 2):

The problem came from a mismatch version between math library on the target and the one I was linking to.